# how to convert List<KeyValuePair<string,object>> to class, model in .Net Core

Tags: list, dictionary, generics, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have got response `List<List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>>` but I want to convert response into `List<ClassName>`.
`KeyValuePair` key and `ClassName` property both are same name and same type

What is the most programmatically way to convert response?

I have got response

[image]

[image]

[image]

My class structure

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string TaxablePersonCode { get; set; }
    public string LegalNameAsPerPan { get; set; }
    public string TradeName { get; set; }
    public string ConstitutionName { get; set; }
    public string ResidentialStatusName { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryMobileNo { get; set; }
    public string FlatOrOfficeNo { get; set; }
    public string TownOrCityOrDist { get; set; }
    public string Pincode { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactDesignationName { get; set; }
    public string ContactMobile { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
}

 var listKeyValue = response.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestModel>>(listKeyValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only part of this im unsure about is when indexing the final list for the correct property, but you can choose what works best for you. Using a `.Where()` every time ensures you'll get the right result but it will search the list every single time and be a lot slower. If your %100 certain the order of the list will never change you could gain some performance by directly indexing the list for the element you want using `[]` or `.ElementAt()`. Anyway, heres what your looking for.

```
List<TestModel> myList = response.Select(x => new TestModel
{
    // Using Where
    TaxablePersonCode = x.Where(t => t.Key == "TaxablePersonCode").First().Value,
    // Using direct index
    LegalNameAsPerPan = x[1].Value,
    // Using ElementAt
    TradeName = x.ElementAt(2).Value,
    ...
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Did you get some result with `JsonConvert` class? Did it worked for you? If not, you can try out something like this (if JSON and field are properly named):

```
var listKeyValue = response.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

var result = new List<TestModel>();
foreach (var keyValueList in listKeyValue)
{
    // convert the response list of KeyValuePair to dictionary
    var dictionary = keyValueList.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);

    var tempModel = new TestModel();

    // get actual value by name of the rpoperty
    tempModel.TaxablePersonCode = dictionary[nameof(tempModel.TaxablePersonCode)].ToString();
    // etc.
    result.Add(tempModel);
}
```

Maybe this approach could be improved with reflection, but this will degrade the performance.

```
// get all properties to populate
var properties = typeof(TestModel).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using JSON, so you should probably just deserialize the object properly, which I would expect to look something like this:

```
List<TestModel> models = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestModel>>(response);
```

Otherwise, you could use reflection to bind the known KeyValuePair keys to the properties of the object; that being said, you will need to ensure that the return values are compatible with the values from the returned data, else this will fail.

```
outerList.ForEach(innerList => {
    TestModel result = new TestModel();
    innerList.ForEach(listItem => {
        result
            .GetType()
            .GetProperty(listItem.Key)
            ?.SetValue(result, listItem.Value); 
    });
});
```